# Creating Pivot Chart from Excel Macro

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I have written a macro to create a Pivot chart in Excel in one Workbook. If I am running the macro from the same workbook it is adding the pivot chart proper without any error.
But if I am running the macro from another workbook, I am getting the Application defined or Object defined error in following line.

`ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=PRange, Version:=xlPivotTableVersion15).CreatePivotTable TableDestination:=DSheet.Cells(Table1_Start_Line, Column_Line), TableName:="HSDPivotTable", DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion15`

My Complete code is below

```
Sub InsertPivotTable()
'Macro By ExcelChamps

'Declare Variables
Dim PSheet As Worksheet
Dim DSheet As Worksheet
Dim PCache As PivotCache
Dim PTable As PivotTable
Dim PTable1 As PivotTable
Dim PRange As Range
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastCol As Long

Dim Table1_Row_line As Integer
Dim Table1_Column_line As Integer
Dim Table2_Row_line As Integer
Dim Table2_Column_line As Integer

Dim Chart1_Row_Line As Integer
Dim Chart1_Column_Line As Integer
Dim Chart2_Row_Line As Integer
Dim Chart2_Column_Line As Integer

'Insert a New Blank Worksheet
'On Error Resume Next
Set DSheet = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate

'Define Data Range
LastRow = DSheet.Cells(DSheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
LastCol = DSheet.Cells(1, DSheet.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Set PRange = DSheet.Cells(1, 1).Resize(LastRow, LastCol)

Table1_Start_Line = 2
Table1_End_Line = Table1_Start_Line + LastRow
Column_Line = LastCol + 2

Table2_Start_Line = Table1_End_Line + 2
Table2_End_Line = Table2_Start_Line + LastRow


ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=PRange, Version:=xlPivotTableVersion15).CreatePivotTable TableDestination:=DSheet.Cells(Table1_Start_Line, Column_Line), TableName:="PivotTable", DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion15
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
DSheet.Cells(Table1_Start_Line, Column_Line).Select

With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable").PivotFields("WW")
.Orientation = xlRowField
.Position = 1
End With

ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable").PivotFields("Actual"), "Actual ", xlSum
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable").PivotFields("Actual(cumulative)"), "Actual (cumulative) ", xlSum

ActiveWorkbook.ShowPivotTableFieldList = False
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(201, xlColumnClustered).Select
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("Sheet1!$Z$" & Table1_Start_Line & ":$AB$" & Table1_End_Line)
    ActiveChart.SetElement (msoElementChartTitleAboveChart)
    ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Text = "Chart1"
    Selection.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = "Chart1"

ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").PivotTables("PivotTable").PivotCache.CreatePivotTable TableDestination:=DSheet.Cells(Table2_Start_Line, Column_Line), TableName:="IncomingVsCompletion", DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion15
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Cells(Table2_Start_Line, Column_Line).Select
ActiveWorkbook.ShowPivotTableFieldList = True
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("IncomingVsCompletion").PivotFields("WW")
.Orientation = xlRowField
.Position = 1
End With

ActiveSheet.PivotTables("IncomingVsCompletion").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables("IncomingVsCompletion").PivotFields("Plan"), "Plan ", xlSum
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("IncomingVsCompletion").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables("IncomingVsCompletion").PivotFields("Plan (cumulative)"), "Plan (cumulative) ", xlSum

ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(201, xlColumnClustered).Select
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("Sheet1!$Z$" & Table2_Start_Line & ":$AB$" & Table2_End_Line)
    ActiveChart.SetElement (msoElementChartTitleAboveChart)
    ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Text = "Chart2"
    Selection.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = "Chart2"

ActiveWorkbook.ShowPivotTableFieldList = False
End Sub
```

The data in different excel workbooks will be different. I want to create the pivot chart in different workbooks.

Comment: Sometimes splitting that single line of code to two lines can fix this problem (1) create the pivotcache (2) create the pivottable from the pivotcache.  At the least it will help you debug.

Comment: To properly indent your code, paste the code in the question, highlight the code, then press **CTRL + K**

Comment: @TimWilliams I tried creating Pivot Cache and Pivot Table separately. But still getting the same error.